# How do I install the Rails MySQL adapter?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

There's not much more to my question than that. `gem install mysql` doesn't work and I haven't found anything by Googling.

When I try `gem install mysql2`, this is what I get. I don't know what to do now.

```
jason@buster:~/projects/mcif-rails$ gem install mysql2
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing mysql2:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/home/jason/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... yes
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lm... yes
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lz... yes
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lsocket... no
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lnsl... yes
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lmygcc... no
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=/home/jason/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/bin/ruby
        --with-mysql-config
        --without-mysql-config
        --with-mysql-dir
        --without-mysql-dir
        --with-mysql-include
        --without-mysql-include=${mysql-dir}/include
        --with-mysql-lib
        --without-mysql-lib=${mysql-dir}/lib
        --with-mysqlclientlib
        --without-mysqlclientlib
        --with-mlib
        --without-mlib
        --with-mysqlclientlib
        --without-mysqlclientlib
        --with-zlib
        --without-zlib
        --with-mysqlclientlib
        --without-mysqlclientlib
        --with-socketlib
        --without-socketlib
        --with-mysqlclientlib
        --without-mysqlclientlib
        --with-nsllib
        --without-nsllib
        --with-mysqlclientlib
        --without-mysqlclientlib
        --with-mygcclib
        --without-mygcclib
        --with-mysqlclientlib
        --without-mysqlclientlib


Gem files will remain installed in /home/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/mysql2-0.2.6 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/mysql2-0.2.6/ext/mysql2/gem_make.out
```

Comment: What operating system are you running? It looks like you haven't installed MySQL and / or the development libraries required.

Comment: I'm on Linux. MySQL is installed but the dev libraries are almost certainly not. How do I know what those are?

Comment: It depends, what distribution are you using (i.e. Ubuntu, Red Hat, SUSE)?

Comment: Also, where is mysql installed? If it isn't under `/usr/local/mysql` you might need to pass in some options to the gem installation.

Comment: Nevermind - one of the answers gave me what I needed. Thanks anyway. (I'm on Ubuntu if you're curious.)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It looks like you still need to install MySQL's development libraries. These are required for the gem to build successfully on your system.

[Edit] Seems the RoR Wiki is no longer available. But, Ubuntu has offered [their own walkthrough](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RubyOnRails#Configure_the_server) which suggests:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server mysql-client
sudo apt-get install libmysql-ruby libmysqlclient-dev
sudo gem install mysql
```

<s>See http://wiki.rubyonrails.org/database-support/mysql#installation for more detail.</s>

Example: Ubuntu

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server mysql-server-5.0 libmysqlclient15off \
    libmysqlclient15-dev mysql-client-5.0 mysql-common

sudo apt-get install libmysql++-dev

sudo gem install mysql
```

Comment: on Ubuntu 14.04 `libmysql-ruby` no needed

Comment: Also on Ubuntu 14.04 there is no "mysql" package

Answer (score 10):

**I'll just leave this here:**

I ran into a similar problem, then realized I couldn't install the mysql2 gem without having MySQL installed on my development machine (even though I'm only using the mysql2 gem to connect to a remote MySQL server).

::forehead slap::

```
brew install mysql
```

then, in my Gemfile:

```
gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.3.11'
```

followed by a quick

```
bundle install
```

Success!

Answer (score 3):

If you are running Rails 3 you should use the mysql2 gem. You can install it with:

```
gem install mysql2
```

You will need to first install MySQL and any development headers. This will vary across different operating systems. On Ubuntu, you can run:

```
aptitude install mysql-server 
aptitude install mysql-client
aptitude install mysql-common
aptitude install libmysql-ruby
aptitude install libmysqlclient-dev
```

If you are creating a new project, use:

```
rails new sample --database=mysql
cd sample
bundle install
```

For more details, check out the [project repository](https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2).

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are working with Rails.

In your Gemfile:

```
gem 'mysql2'
```

Then in your terminal:

```
bundle
```

Comment: It craps out when it gets to `mysql2` in the same way that it does when I try `gem install mysql2`. I've edited my question to show what happens.

Answer (score 1):

In 2013, Using Ubuntu 12.04, this worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-client libmysqlclient-dev

bundle install
```